# jQuery opacity/fade animation only works once

Tags: jquery, image, animation, hover, fade

I'm building a personal website. I researched and started doing it with CSS keyframes, but found a solution using jQuery + CSS keyframes myself.

My issue now (which I assume have a simple answer that I cannot see because I've been staring at my monitor too long) is that **my hover animation only works once**. That is, upon mouse:hover, my image 1 fades into images 2 (image1 disappears) and then image2 fades into images3 (image2 disappears), so its' like a cascade. However, this is only works once, if I hover again, it won't work.

So to clarify again, I want this animation to cascade-Fade from image1, to image2, to image3, and then reverse out (image3, to image2, to image1, i.e. like some morphing effect) **EVERY-TIME** the user mouse:hovers over the original image.

I'm assuming the answer might do with the `class` "animated" being added but not removed? I actually don't know jQuery but have been teaching myself impromptu and figured if someone else saw my code, they could spot the syntax/bug.

## ALSO

Is this the best method to fade/transistion images to-one-another? I want a SMOOTH fade, like a "morphing" - is this best done the way I'm doing it? (jquery+keyframes), should I add more keyframes for a smoother effect?

**Here is the jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/1xrbxdnk/2/

And the source code:
HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://alpizano.com/assets/images/venom1.png" width="50%" class="top">
  <img src="http://alpizano.com/assets/images/venom2.png" width="50%" class="middle">
  <img src="http://alpizano.com/assets/images/venom3.png" width="50%" class="bottom">
</div>
```

**JavsScript/jQuery**

```
$("img.top").hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("animated");
  $("img.middle").addClass("animated2");
  $("img.bottom").addClass("animated3");
})

$("img.bottom").bind("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd", function() {
    $(this).addClass("animated6")
  $("img.middle").addClass("animated5")
  $("img.top").addClass("animated4")
})
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}

.middle {
  display: none;
}

.bottom {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes anim3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes anim6 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim5 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes anim4 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.top.animated {
  animation: anim1 3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.middle.animated2 {
  animation: anim2 3s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
}

.bottom.animated3 {
  animation: anim3 3s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bottom.animated6 {
  animation: anim6 3s ease-in-out;

  opacity: 0;
}

.middle.animated5 {
  animation: anim5 3s ease-in-out;

  opacity: 0;
}

.top.animated4 {
  animation: anim4 3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the animation classes once the animation is done. You already have an event listener for animation end to add the reverse animations. You could do the following:

```
$("img.bottom").bind("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd",         
function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('animated6')) {
    $(this).addClass("animated6");
    $("img.middle").addClass("animated5");
    $("img.top").addClass("animated4");
  }
  else {
    $(this).removeClass("animated6 animated3");
    $("img.middle").removeClass("animated5 animated2");
    $("img.top").removeClass("animated4 animated");
  }
});
```

Here's your fiddle updated:

http://jsfiddle.net/1xrbxdnk/3/

Here's a snippet:

```js
$("img.top").hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("animated");
  $("img.middle").addClass("animated2");
  $("img.bottom").addClass("animated3");
})

$("img.bottom").bind("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd", function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('animated6')) {
   $(this).addClass("animated6");
    $("img.middle").addClass("animated5");
    $("img.top").addClass("animated4");
  }
  else {
    $(this).removeClass("animated6 animated3");
    $("img.middle").removeClass("animated5 animated2");
    $("img.top").removeClass("animated4 animated");
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}

.middle {
  display: none;
}

.bottom {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes anim3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes anim6 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim5 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes anim4 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.top.animated {
  animation: anim1 3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.middle.animated2 {
  animation: anim2 3s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
}

.bottom.animated3 {
  animation: anim3 3s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bottom.animated6 {
  animation: anim6 3s ease-in-out;

  opacity: 0;
}

.middle.animated5 {
  animation: anim5 3s ease-in-out;

  opacity: 0;
}

.top.animated4 {
  animation: anim4 3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://alpizano.com/assets/images/venom1.png" width="50%" class="top">
  <img src="http://alpizano.com/assets/images/venom2.png" width="50%" class="middle">
  <img src="http://alpizano.com/assets/images/venom3.png" width="50%" class="bottom">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know jQuery so I was having issues, I am digesting your code and I see how you put the if/else conditions in there to add and remove the class, thank you very much.

Comment: No problem! By the way, if the reverse animation is exactly the reverse of the beginning animation, you could look into "animation-direction: alternate" css property. And if you my answer worked for you, you could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

for repetitiveness you have to remove the anim. classes and also bind the hover function to the parent div.box

```
$(".box").hover(function() {

  $("img.top").removeClass().addClass("top");
  $("img.middle").removeClass().addClass("middle");
  $("img.bottom").removeClass().addClass("bottom");

  $(this).addClass("animated");
  $("img.middle").addClass("animated2");
  $("img.bottom").addClass("animated3");
})

$("img.bottom").bind("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd", function() {
    $(this).addClass("animated6")
  $("img.middle").addClass("animated5")
  $("img.top").addClass("animated4")
})
```

Comment: I copied that into jfiddle and it didn't quite work but thank you providing some help, I think I got it now, I greatly appreciate it.